# Visual Studio 2015: Intellisense string errors but solution compiles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, upgrade, intellisense, c-strings

As someone mentioned in a similar post (post with same name), I recently switched over to vs2015 and am seeing Intellisense errors which I did not see in the last vs version. These red squiggle Intellisense errors do not equate to compile errors.

What is bad about this is it makes Intellisense less useful since it is flagging errors which I am pretty sure are not errors.

The main error which is showing up is a conversion between to very basic string types; the std::string and the CString. Previously you could easily do the following:

```
CString str_1 = "HI";
std::string = str_1;
```

Although this is not a compiler error, Intellisense sees this as an error which is making the Intellisense less useful right now. I guess I'll end up correcting these lines eventually (if need be) but these weren't previously Intellisense errors.

Tried some tricks mentioned in other post (remove suo, remove/add reference) but the red squiggle still exist.

The Intellisense error is:

Error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "CString" to "std::string" exists

Comment: After I see this code I would put "red squiggle" too.

Comment: What *does* IntelliSense say? It could be helpful to know and could help us understand the problem.

Comment: A better question is why that code compiles in the first place.

Comment: I think it compiles because CString has (or used to have - it's a decade or more since I used it) an operator const char*.  std::string has a constructor which takes const char *.